# Getting error 'Endpoint' object has no attribute ctrl_transfer when trying to get string descriptor using pyusb

Tags: python, pyusb

I am attempting to get the string descriptor of the Endpoint attribute bmAttributes. I am able to get the value using pyusb but not the string descriptor for it. When i do i get that error.

```
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor = 0x0126)
dev.set_configuration()
cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
intf = cfg[(0,0)]
ep = intf[0]

bmattrib = usb.util.get_string(ep, ep.bmAttributes) <--Where error is
```

I can get the value but not the string. Anyone know how to get this to work?